# Pass value trough Angular2 on view change

Tags: angular, typescript, google-visualization, google-gauges

I'd like to Update my Google Chart when the Angular2 value has changed.

In my Angular2 test.component.html, I have a Template like this:

```
<h1>
  Test Chart
</h1>

<div>
  // I want to bind this value with Goolgle Gauge
  {{parameter.value}}
</div>

<div class="gauge">
  <google-chart [data]="gaugeChartOptions"></google-chart>
</div>
```

And my Angular2 test.component.ts looks like this:

```
export class ChartTestComponent implements OnInit {

  public parameter: Parameter;

  public gaugeChartOptions = {
    chartType: 'Gauge',
    dataTable: [
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Value', 5] // I'd like to bind it with {{parameter.value}}
    ],
    options: {
      width: 200, height: 250,
      redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5
    },
  };

  constructor(private parameterService: ParameterService) {
  }

  changeVal(value: number) {
    this.gaugeChartOptions = Object.create(this.gaugeChartOptions);
    this.gaugeChartOptions.dataTable[1][1] =  Number(value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.parameter =  this.parameterService.getByPath('test_signal/10_Hz');
  }


}
```

How can I change the Gauge value with {{parameter.value}}?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the "Gauge value"? Where or what is "Google gauge" in your code?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

Comment: Ok, so `<google-chart ...` is the Gauge. What value do you want to get from gauge? One of `gaugeChartOptions`?

Comment: Exactly, I want to bind gaugeChartOptions -> dataTable -> ['Value', 5] with {{parameter.value}}

Comment: What about `{{gaugeChartOptions.dataTable[1] | json}}`? What is `parameter.value` supposed to do or mean?

Comment: What do you mean with "I'd like to change this value '5'? Do you want to bind or to change? When do you want to change and to what value?

Comment: `parameter.value` changes 10 times pro second It's a number between 0-100. Wich I obtain from json RESTful. I'd like to update it with gaugeChartOptions.dataTable[1][1].

Comment: What about `{{gaugeChartOptions.dataTable[1][1]}}` then?

Comment: I want to bind `{{gaugeChartOptions.dataTable[1][1]}}` with  `{{parameter.value}}`

Comment: Sorry, can't make any sense of your question or this comment.